# Contour graph curve intersection

Tags: plotting

How do I show intersecting points on a contour graph? I have 2 functions graphed but I cannot figure out how to show the points of their intersections.

Comment: Please be more specific: you have the expression of f and g? If you want the intersection of the 2 graphs, try to plot f - g = 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f[x_, y_] := Abs[Sin[x] Sin[y]] - .5
g[x_, y_] := Abs[Cos[x] Cos[y]] - .25
```

Three alternative methods:

**1.** Use [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) to find the intersections and add the intersection points as [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html) in `ContourPlot`:

```
intersections = {x, y} /. 
   Solve[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0, -3 <= x <= 3 && -3 <= y <= 3}, {x, y}];

ContourPlot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point@intersections}]
```

[image]

**2.** Use `` Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections `` to find the intersections of contour lines and add the corresponding points using a combination of options `Epilog` and [`DisplayFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DisplayFunction.html):

```
ContourPlot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
 DisplayFunction -> (Show[#, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], 
   Point@Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[#[[1]], Graphics`Mesh`AllPoints -> False]}] &)]
```

[image]

**3.**  Use the options [`MeshFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html) and [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html):

```
ContourPlot[{f[x, y] == 0, g[x, y] == 0}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
 MeshFunctions -> {g[#, #2] - f[#, #2] &}, 
 Mesh -> {{{0, Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]}}}]
```

[image]

**Note:** The last two methods do not work if some contours are tangent to each other.